# Is there a trick to compute this multinomial-looking sum?

Tags: derivatives, summation, contest-math, multinomial-coefficients

The series I want to sum has this form

$\displaystyle \sum_{} 1^{l_1}(1+c)^{l_2} (1+2c)^{l_3} \cdot \ldots \cdot  (1+(N-1)c)^{l_{N}}$

for some constant $c$ and positive integers $N$ and $L$. Here the sum is taken over all ordered (finite) sequences $(l_1,l_2, \ldots , l_N)$ that satisfy $l_1+l_2+ \ldots l_N = L$. There are exactly $ {L+N-1} \choose {N-1}$ such sequences and the same number of terms to sum.

The reason this looks like the [multinomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) is because it came out of something similar. In particular it came out of the similar formula for the order-$L$ [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) of a product of $N$ many functions. The only difference is those formulas have coefficients that depend on $(l_1,l_2, \ldots , l_N)$.

So this guy is screaming out that he wants to be recovered as a coefficient of something. For example if I were to add up all the terms $1,1+c,1+2c,\ldots, 1+(N-1)c$ I'd get $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}c$. Then I could take the $L$-th power to get

$\displaystyle \left (\frac{n(n-1)}{2}c \right )^L = \Big( 1 + (1+c) + \ldots + (1 + (N-1)c)\Big )^L = \sum {L \choose{l_1 , \ldots , l_N}} 1^{l_1}(1+c)^{l_2} (1+2c)^{l_3} \cdot \ldots \cdot  (1+(N-1)c)^{l_{N}}$

where the last line uses the multinomial formula. Then I can compute the right-hand-side by computing the much easier left-hand-side. Except the right-hand-side is the wrong series!

Is there any trick to get rid of these pesky coefficients? One idea I had was to replace each $(1+mc)$ with some function which, when differentiated $l_m$ times adds an exponent of $l_m$ and a constant factor that cancels out the multinomial coefficients in the product rule. That would work if the left-hand-side looked like some easy to differentiate function. Unfortunately I already know what that function looks like, and it is the function that I derived the series from.

**Edit:** If we write $[L,N]$ for the sum above he satisfies the recurrence $[L,N] = (1+(N-1))[L-1,N]$ + [L,N-1] if anyone has ideas for that. Generating functions maybe?

Comment: Your sum is the coefficient of $t^L$ in the power series $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} \dfrac{1}{1-\left(1+kc\right)t}$. While I doubt this has a nice explicit form, it looks closely related to some standard generating functions for Stirling numbers.

Comment: Stirling numbers give the answer for $c=1$. The general case can only be harder.

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Comment: This question comes out of trying to compute a certain probability associated with linear combinations of exponential random variables. Of course it LOOKS like some classic Olympiad-type problem which is why I thought is was worth posting in case someone had seen it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $c=1$ we have

$\displaystyle \sum_{} 1^{l_1}2^{l_2} 3^{l_3} \cdot \ldots \cdot  N^{l_{N}} = {{N+L} \brace N}$

are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Write $(L,N)$ for the sum above. For each $(l_1, l_2 \ldots , l_N)$ we have either $l_N \ge 1$ or $l_N = 0$. The sequences with the first property correspond to the sequences $(l_1,l_2, \ldots , l_{N-1}, l_N-1)$ with sum $L-1$. It follows the sum over all such sequences is $N(L-1,N)$. The sequences with the second property correspond to the sequences $(l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_{N-1})$ with sum $L$. It follows the sum over all such sequences is $(L,N-1)$. Thus we have the recurrence $(L,N) = $ $N(L-1,N) + (L,N-1)$.

By iterating the recurrence we can express any given $(L,N)$ in terms of some collection of values $(1, \widetilde N)$ and $(\widetilde L,1)$. It follows any doubly-indexed sequence $C^L_N$ that satisfies the same recurrence and has all $C^L_1 = (L,1)$ and $C^1_N = (1,N)$ must have all $C^L_N = (L,N)$.

For a [similar reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation) we see $C^L_N =  {{N+L} \brace {N}}$ satisfies the recurrence. It remains to show each $(L,1) = {{L+1} \brace 1} $ and $(1,N) = {{N+1} \brace N }$.

Clearly each $(L,1) = 1$. Since there is exactly one way to partition a set of $L+1$ elements into exactly one subset we have ${L+1 \brace 1}=1$ as well.

By definition each $(1,N) = 1 + 2 + \ldots + N = N(N+1)/2$ by the well-known formula. To compute ${{N+1} \brace N }$ observe each partition of $N+1$ into $N$ subsets consists of $N-1$ singletons and $1$ doubleton. Thus ${{N+1} \brace N }$ is just the number of doubletons of $N+1$ which is just ${N+1 \choose 2} = N(N+1)/2$. This completes the proof.